# What is the difference  in php5 between $this and &$this

Tags: php

I have some confusion about $this and &$this, please describe this point .

#### Update:

Thanks for reply.  I know about pass by value and pass by reference. Please see the following program.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class my_class
{
    var $my_var;
    function my_class ($var)
    {
        global $obj_instance;
        $obj_instance = $this;
        $this->my_var = $var;
    }
}
$obj = new my_class ("something");
echo $obj->my_var;
echo $obj_instance->my_var;
////////////////////////////////////
```

In this program `$obj_instance = $this;` is copy the variable but output of this somethingsomething but when I am using  `$obj_instance = &$this;` the output is somethings.  Why is it different?

Thank you.

Comment: hi thanks to see by question please can any describe the program and resolve by confusion i am very thank to you.

Comment: hi thanks to reply it not a matter of accessibility i only want to know about program $obj_instance = $this; is copy the variable but output of this somethingsomething but when i am using $obj_instance = &$this; out put is somethings why?

Comment: my php error on but i am not getting any notice and warning try to run this script. you defiantly get whats a problem and easy to understand

Comment: what @Gordon says answers your question - the reference to `&$this` that you pass to `$object_instance` will be valid only for as long as the function runs. Outside it, it will expire. You should be getting a warning.

Comment: but i am not getting any notice and warning while running a script please run it and confirm.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. Quoting http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php:

> If you assign a reference to a variable declared global inside a function, the reference will be visible only inside the function. You can avoid this by using the $GLOBALS array.

and thus the result of your code is just "something". It will also emit a notice about "Trying to get property of non-object" (when error reporting is enabled).